# How can I use ABS() and minus opertator in typerom querybuilder orderBy function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to order by the closest latitude using this sql query

```
ORDER BY ABS(a.latitude  - 41.876698387331906) ASC
```

It works fine,

But in typeorm when I try

```
.orderBy('ABS(address.latitude - 41.41.876698387331906)', 'ASC')
```

It tells me that the relation 'ABS(address' doesn't exist.
Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the **ABS** in you select as the following:

```
.addSelect('ABS(address.latitude - 41.41.876698387331906)', 'absLat')
```

and then order by **absLat**

```
.orderBy('absLat', 'ASC')
```